# Epiphany Browser in full screen mode

Tags: raspbian

How do I start epiphany browser in fullscreen mode from terminal (not F11)? Documentation says to use arguments `-f` or `--fullscreen` but neither of them work.

Comment: What version of Epiphany are you running? 3.8.2 which is what is installed on my system does not have either of those options. You can check the version with epiphany --version and the available commands with man epiphany. This is one of the reasons I ma using chromium to display my dashboards and monitoring screens. You may be able to get bash/xdotools to launch epiphany and simulate hitting the f11 key to switch to fullscreen mode.

Comment: I was using chromium but the problem with Chromium is that it cannot run HTML5 videos. Thats why I had to switch back to epiphany. I tried using xautomation to simulate F11 but that does not work either.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can start it in kiosk mode using `-a`, you may have to create your `~/.config` for your profile.

```
epiphany-browser -a --profile ~/.config http://localhost/index.html
```

Comment: What do you mean by I might by have to create a ~/.config for my profile? What does it do?

Comment: if you try to run it in app mode before the "~/.config" folder is set up epiphany won't run. it needs that folder at least created for it to store cookies adblock data bookmarks and other db data epiphany uses.

 mkdir ~/.config

Comment: simply change `~/.config` to `/home/pi/.config` when you put this in `/etc/rc.local` and it works like a charm

Answer (score 11):

Here is how I got the default browser ephiphany working in Kiosk Mode.
First I set the `sudo raspi-config` boot option to b2 "command prompt with auto login"

Create a file startB in your home directory `/home/pi/` with following content
`sudo nano ./startB`

```bash
#!/bin/sh
xset -dpms # disable DPMS (Energy Star) features.
xset s off # disable screen saver
xset s noblank # don't blank the video device
matchbox-window-manager -use_titlebar no &
WEBKIT_DISABLE_TBS=1 epiphany-browser -a --profile /home/pi/.config  http://site
```

now sudo nano `/etc/rc.local` and put in the following line before exit 0

```
sudo xinit ./home/pi/startB &
```

and Raspberry Pi will boot up in kiosk mode with browser.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was the first script that I was able to run on a Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian Jessie with an Adafruit PiTFT. The browser now starts up full screen on the TFT screen. Cheers!

Comment: I've just done this.  Thanks for the tip, but it's only opening in the top left quarter of the screen.  Any ideas how I make sure it opens full screen?

Comment: Same issue as @TobyG, it runs in the top-left corner, 33% screen width and 50% height.

Comment: thanks, works for me! but i wonder why `WEBKIT_DISABLE_TBS=1` is set and what it is supposed to do. wasn't that relevant in regards to **kweb**?

Comment: Did not work: the top menu was still visible. When I closed epiphany, I realized that the keyboard was disabled; the screen randomly jumps up and down by ~20 pixels. Warning: at that point, recovering is not easy; I was able to delete the batch file and restart using the mouse (which still worked).

Answer (score 6):

I got it working with xautomation.  I didn't have any success with "-a".

The script I'm using is:

```
xte 'sleep 10' 'key F11'&
epiphany-browser test.html
```

This code sends an F11 keystroke 10 seconds after starting the browser.

That was after I installed xautomation, which provides the xte command:

```
root@nexus:/home/pi/bin# aptitude install xautomation
```

Answer (score 5):

I got success after tried this.

Save this shell script to: `/home/pi/fullscreen.sh`

```
sudo -u pi epiphany-browser -a --profile ~/.config http://127.0.0.1/index.html --display=:0 &
sleep 15s;
xte "key F11" -x:0
```

`&` is important. This mark is ignoring errors from the epiphany-browser.
I added `&` mark because I got an error after I tried this shell script on the command line.

```
sudo apt-get install epiphany-browser
sudo apt-get install xautomation

sudo vi /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
@/home/pi/fullscreen.sh

sudo chmod 755 /home/pi/fullscreen.sh
```

(sorry my english is poor because I am japanese.)

Answer (score 2):

The `-a` flag doesn't result in fullscreen for me, and as `F11` toggles fullscreen (rather than just setting it) I wanted something more concrete.

I ended up using `wmctrl -r "<name of window>" -b add,fullscreen` which *sets* fullscreen instead of toggling and calling this in a loop while the browser process is still running. Epiphany responds to this the same as if you'd just pressed F11, hiding the nav bar and removing window decorations.

```
# disable screensaver and screen blanking
xset -dpms s off

# create profile folder if it doesn't exist
mkdir -p /home/<user>/.config/epiphany-kiosk

# launch the browser as a background process
epiphany-browser -a --profile /home/<user>/.config/epiphany-kiosk http://localhost:8000/ &

# see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20165094/66349
# get the browser PID
pid=$!

# If this script is killed, kill the main process.
trap "kill $pid 2> /dev/null" EXIT

# Loop while it's running...
while kill -0 $pid 2> /dev/null; do
    wmctrl -r "<name of window>" -b add,fullscreen
    sleep 2
done

# Disable the trap on a normal exit.
trap - EXIT
```

Answer (score 1):

I find that using a delay between the epiphany launch command and the xte sucks. I looked for a better way (and more reliable).

My first attempt was to open epiphany on a php file that would execute the xte command: `<?php $out = shell_exec("xte 'key F11'"); ?>`
Unfortunately it does not work. Cannot tell you why though (if someone knows, I am interested). When I echo the output with `xte -h` I do get the help of xte command on my webpage... Anyway I did not have much time, so I try another way around.

The idea is still to launch epiphany to a php file (fs.php) that contains:

```
$h = fopen("/var/www/fs/FS.chk", "w");
#fwrite($h, "browser opened"); # <- don't really need this
fclose($h);
```

For launching the web browser I will use a bash script that can be run after the boot, or anytime you want. The script contains:

```
if [ -e "var/www/fs/FS.chk" ]; then
rm -f /var/www/fs/FS.chk
fi

epiphany localhost/fs/fs.php &

until [ -e "/var/www/fs/FS.chk" ]
do
sleep 0.1
done

xte "key F11"
```

As you noticed, my working directory is /var/www/fs/. But you can adapt this to your need. Also, it is quite easy to add a redirection on the php file to switch to the desired webpage once the web browser is running on full screen mode.

The php code create a *witness* (FS.chk) file while the bash, after having launched epiphany to this php file, is looking for the *witness* file. This file is only created once epiphany is opened (that get rids off the 15s sleep in previous posts). Once the bash sees the *witness* file, it executes the xte command...

EDIT: I just find out that it is important not to add "http://" before the URL passed to epiphany. If you do, the xte command will be issued, apparently, too soon.

Answer (score 1):

Do like this! GoTo: https://github.com/elalemanyo/raspberry-pi-kiosk-screen

create the file: `nano /home/pi/fullscreen.sh`

paste this into fullscreen.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep  20
if [ -z "$(pgrep epiphany)" ];
   then (sudo -u pi epiphany-browser -a -i --profile ~/.config http://www.na.se --display=:0) &
   sleep 5s;
   xte "key F11" -x:0;
fi
bash $0 &
```

And then if your browser crashes, it will come to live again :)

Answer (score 0):

xte has an option to send commands to remote (or local displays)

it is simpler to use the -x xte option :

```
epiphany --display=:0 [http://YOURURL]
sleep 20 && xte -x :0 "key F11"
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Follow @Jacobm001 and @Adeel post but after all that modify:

```
~/.config/states.xml
```

modify `#property id="3" value_type="gint">1920< #width`
modify `#property id="3" value_type="gint">1080< #height`

match these above to the resolution of your device.  My comment sections are not in the states.xml file.

Save and Reboot

Answer (score -2):

Don't forget to make your script executable!

```
sudo chmod +x /home/pi/startB
```